# laravel unique validation field already exists

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-8

i tried to ignore code when user trying to modify his profile, but throw me error: Code already exists.

Here is my code:

Table: users

```
id       email
1 user1@example.com 
2 user2@example.com
3 user3@example.com
4 user4@example.com
```

Table: profiles

```
id        user_id          code 
1            3             er1254
2            4             zk1299



$validatedData = $this->validate([
    'code' => 'required|unique:profiles,code,'.Auth::user()->id,
]);
```

always give me this code already exists... what's wrong with my validation please? I want to ignore verification to allow user modify his profile without changing the code.

Comment: You need to use [Rule::unique if you want to ignore an id](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-unique)

Comment: The syntax you're currently using to ignore an `id` is for Laravel versions 4.2 to 5.2, as it was updated in 5.3 to suggest the `Rule::unique()` approach. You have this question tagged as `laravel-8`, so use the proper syntax. If for some reason you _need_ to use this syntax, your issue is likely that you're targeting `profiles.id` and not `profiles.user_id` (I assume you'd wanting to ignore `user_id` since you're using `Auth::user()->id`). Syntax for that would be `'code' => 'required|unique:profiles,code,' . auth()->user()->id . ',user_id'`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try the [Rule::unique()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-unique).

Here is what that might look for your example.

```
$validateData = this->validate([
    "code" => "required|".Rule::unique('code')->ignore(request()->id)
```

This would allow you to update the record and ignore the unique requirement if it has the same id.

Note, you may need to modify the code to suit your  specific needs.

Answer (score 0):

you should update your validation like this:

```
$validatedData = $this->validate([
    'code' => [
        'required',
        Rule::unique('profiles', 'code')->where(function ($query) {
            return $query->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
        })->ignore(Auth::user()->profile->id),
    ],
]);
```

The `profile` in `Auth::user()->profile->id` is assumed to be a relationship between the `User` model and the `Profile` model.

Comment: I did this and it works fine, I don't know id it's good? 'code' => 'required|unique:profiles,code,'.$this->codeId, because I have function mount where I did $this->codeId= $profile->id; Is it good this approach?

Comment: Yes, in the mount method, you've set `$this->codeId` to the `id` of the `user's profile`.  Also in the validation rule, you are using `$this->codeId` to specify that the uniqueness check should ignore the current user's profile `id` when checking for uniqueness.
It is important to capture and use the current user's profile `id` to ensure that the uniqueness check is performed within the context of the user's own profile.